# `Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...` never end and no error, only when its run with ios simulator

Tags: flutter, xcode

I want to run ios simulator on debug mode with flutter and vscode.
I can run debug mode with Macos(desktop), Chrome(web) and android, but not ios simulator.

When I did F5 or flutter run it is stuck with below message for long long time. No error.
`Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...`
`[  +94 ms] <- compile package:first_test_app/main.dart` last log and stuck here.

What I did

- `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` and `sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch`
- `flutter devices`
- check the connection between vscode and ios simulator on vscode
- `flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on macOS 13.4.1 22F770820d darwin-x64, locale ja-JP)
    • Flutter version 3.10.6 on channel stable at /Users/me/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f468f3366c (13 days ago), 2023-07-12 15:19:05 -0700
    • Engine revision cdbeda788a
    • Dart version 3.0.6
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/me/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E300c
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.80.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.68.0

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554                        • android-x64    • Android 14 (API 34) (emulator)
    • iPhone 14 Pro Max (mobile)   • E21198DB-1115-4ABE-B695-4FDE252AA347 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-4 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)              • macos                                • darwin-x64     • macOS 13.4.1 22F770820d darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 115.0.5790.114

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

- `flutter clean` nothing changes.
- Checked command line tools in xcode
- Mac's restart

After I did this still nothing changes.

What should I do for solve this problem?
why my flutter run got stuck when I run with IOS simulator? Something wrong with xcode? I did intall them from AppleStore.

xcode 14.3.1
vscode 1.80.1
flutter 3.10.6
Macos Ventura 13.4.1

Comment: is your main.dart contain any location or any other services? did you try la default counter app to run simulator ?

Comment: @mageshmagi yes I did use default counter app.
I did only flutter create first_test_app and cd first_test_app then flutter run.

Comment: Same problem with Intellij 2023.2.5 (Community Edition) and MacOS Sonoma 14.1.1